# How to find whether all the values in an array is equal or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a array in which some elements has type of farmer and some elements doesn't have the key type.I would like to check the array if all the elements in the array has type is farmer then i would set the value as sourceType as Farmer.
If the element doesn't have the key type in it then i will set the value as SourceType as Godown
If the element contains both (with the key as type and without the key type)then i would set the value as soruceType as Multiple

I have tried with some but i am getting the value as undefined can anyone tell me the fastest apprach where i can check all the elements in the array.

Structure:

```
[
  {id: 2269, name: "Agalya", mobile_no: "1234567890", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 2322, name: "andhra ", mobile_no: "0123456789", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 2366, name: "edwin", mobile_no: "234567890", location: "Madurai", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 99, name: "G12", location: "Vgff", capacity: "5", user_id: 362},
  {id: 126, name: "Pattrai A", location: "Erode", capacity: "88", user_id: 362}
]
```

Comment: This should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813732/how-do-i-check-if-all-elements-of-an-array-are-null

Comment: Show your code and explain, why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = [
                  {id: 2269, name: "Agalya", mobile_no: "1234567890", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
                  {id: 2322, name: "andhra ", mobile_no: "0123456789", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
                  {id: 2366, name: "edwin", mobile_no: "234567890", location: "Madurai", type: "Farmer"},
                  {id: 99, name: "G12", location: "Vgff", capacity: "5", user_id: 362},
                  {id: 126, name: "Pattrai A", location: "Erode", capacity: "88", user_id: 362}
            ];

var SourceType = '';

let farmerArray = array.filter(function (item) {
    return item.type && item.type === "Farmer";
});

let goDownArray = array.filter(function (item) {
    return !item.type;
});



if (farmerArray && farmerArray.count != 0 && farmerArray.length == array.length) { SourceType = 'Farmer'; }
else if (goDownArray && goDownArray.count != 0 && goDownArray.length == array.length) { SourceType = 'Godown'; }
else { SourceType = 'Multiple'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet. It is simple and short.

By changing array name from input1 to input2 or input3 in below code you can test all cases.

```
if( input1.every(element => element.type === "Farmer") ) {
  console.log("Farmer");
}
else if(input1.every(element => ! element.hasOwnProperty("type"))) {
  console.log("Godown");
}
else {
  console.log("Multiple");
}
```

```js
var input1 = [
  {id: 2269, name: "Agalya", mobile_no: "1234567890", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 2322, name: "andhra ", mobile_no: "0123456789", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 2366, name: "edwin", mobile_no: "234567890", location: "Madurai", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 99, name: "G12", location: "Vgff", capacity: "5", user_id: 362},
  {id: 126, name: "Pattrai A", location: "Erode", capacity: "88", user_id: 362}
];

var input2 = [
  {id: 2269, name: "Agalya", mobile_no: "1234567890", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 2322, name: "andhra ", mobile_no: "0123456789", location: "Erode", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 2366, name: "edwin", mobile_no: "234567890", location: "Madurai", type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 99, name: "G12", location: "Vgff", capacity: "5", user_id: 362, type: "Farmer"},
  {id: 126, name: "Pattrai A", location: "Erode", capacity: "88", user_id: 362, type: "Farmer"}
];

var input3 = [
  {id: 2269, name: "Agalya", mobile_no: "1234567890", location: "Erode"},
  {id: 2322, name: "andhra ", mobile_no: "0123456789", location: "Erode"},
  {id: 2366, name: "edwin", mobile_no: "234567890", location: "Madurai"},
  {id: 99, name: "G12", location: "Vgff", capacity: "5", user_id: 362},
  {id: 126, name: "Pattrai A", location: "Erode", capacity: "88", user_id: 362}
];


if( input1.every(element => element.type === "Farmer") ) {
  console.log("Farmer");
}
else if(input1.every(element => ! element.hasOwnProperty("type"))) {
  console.log("Godown");
}
else {
  console.log("Multiple");
}
```